# A truly amazing way of making the number 2016

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

> Find a mathematical expression that yields the value $2016$ while obeying the following rules:

> 

- Each of the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ is used **exactly once**
- Decimal points are allowed
- You may use brackets "(" and ")" to structure your expression, and to make it well-defined
- The only allowed mathematical operations are addition (+), subtraction (-), multiplication (*) and division (÷)
- The only allowed mathematical functions are square-roots and logarithms.
  Logarithms must be written in the form $\log[b](x)$ to denote the base-$b$ logarithm of number $x$

Note that in particular the following is **not allowed**:

- Juxtaposition of digits (as juxtaposing 1 and 3 to get "31")
- other mathematical operations and functions (cube-roots, exponentiation, factorials, absolute values, trigonometric functions, etc)
- matrices and determinants
- integration, differentiation, limits

Comment: So writing $\log[b](x)$ counts as using $b$ and $x$, right?

Comment: @Arnaud D: Yes.

Comment: 2016 is too easily factorable for this to be a challenge.

Comment: Some more restrictive rules could be imposed.

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal points are allowed"? Do you mean numbers like $.7$? Also, you should specify whether or not $0$ is allowed.

Comment: I tried writing a computer program for this as a challenge. Boy, was it a challenge. Especially the log and the sqrt are a pain because the first one uses two numbers and the second one doesn't necessarily use a number.

Comment: All the Perry-style solutions proposed so far use only the operations $+$, $-$, and $\times$. There are $\frac{3^8 \cdot 16!}{8! \cdot 9!} = 9,382,230$ such expressions using the digits $1$ to $9$ in sequence. I suppose one could just simple-mindedly calculate the values of all of them, and see which ones work out to be $2016$. It's easily computationally feasible, but it might be fun to try to think of a less stupid method! Or else, it might be idiotic to become obsessed with such a silly idea. I'm trying to make myself not think about it now. Damn. :)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley By my reckoning, there are exactly 32,282 expressions with 1-9 in order, including `Log` and `Sqrt`.  Equating expressions that differ only by associations, I get around 3,300 distinct expressions.  I'll post the exact count in an answer later.

Comment: Saw the title and thought "Large number constructors hate him! See how he makes 2016 with this one weird trick!"

Comment: @Gamow I now suspect this puzzle was preparatory (as throwing off tack) for your next one
http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28444/a-truly-amazing-way-of-making-every-possible-positive-integer 
Am I correct?

Comment: Anyway, I think this puzzle deserves to became a New Year's Eve Game! Maybe only admitting elementary operations, and with variations of the rules decided randomly. Also, base 10 notation seems to give a wilder and more random combinatory, which is good.

Comment: I just want to point it out that if you check [this wonderful answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28465/20012) you will realize that there are ***366*** possible combinations of 2016 using solely the "-", "+" and "*" operations. It happens that 2016 is a leap year, which means you can have 1 solution for every day. I find this more satisfying than I should.

Comment: The coolest way to write $2016$ is $(10\times 9\times 8\times 7\times 6) / (5+4+3+2+1)$.  It does not actually answer the question but it is cool anyway.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> ((9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 2) / 3) + 5 - 4 - 1

And three more *à la Perry*

> 1 * (2 - 3 + 4 - 5 + 6) * 7 * 8 * 9
>  (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7) * 8 * 9
>  1 * (2 + 3 + 4 + 5) * 6 * (7 + 8 + 9)

Comment: I particularly like the second of those three 'monotonic' solutions!

Comment: the third reminds me of something...

Comment: New year's $2017$ update: $$1+(2-3+4-5+6)\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot9$$ $$1+(2+3+4+5)\cdot 6\cdot (7+ 8+9)$$

Answer (score 49):

> (((1 - 2) x (3 + 4)) + 5 + 6) x 7 x 8 x 9

Comment: nice monotonicity

Answer (score 37):

For those interested, [here](http://pastebin.com/Up2U2VFh) is a brute-forced list of all "monotonic" expressions that use addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. There's 835 of them in total.

**EDIT:** For extra fun, [here](http://pastebin.com/Xs7efEy5) is a list of the 1,151 expressions that use 9 through 1 in order!

Comment: LOL! It's quite worrying how much this pleases me. :) By the way, what programming language did you use?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I just used a small C# program. I would also include logarithms, but it makes the program explode.

Comment: It would also be funny looking at monotonic expressions allowing the base 10 notation, like (12+345)*6-... I wonder if there is any giving 2016!

Comment: e.g. 9*(8+6*7*5+4)-3+21

Comment: @PietroMajer Sadly, that would also make the program explode.

Comment: Couldn't you just replace the ordered 9-uple (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) e.g with the 8-uple (12,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and then check them all? after all there are  only 2^8 ways of gluing together these digits (remove a comma or not) to get shorter k-uples, and for sure the last ones like (123, 456, 789) are trivial...

Comment: @PietroMajer I tried, but the GC doesn't optimize it too well.

Answer (score 19):

Since 2016 is a multiple of 504 = 7 x 8 x 9, any expression using 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 that evaluates to 4 can just multiply those three afterwards and evaluate to 2016.

So all the following are correct:

9 x 8 x 7 x (6 - 5) x 4 x (3 - 2) x 1 = 2016
9 x 8 x 7 x (6 - 5) x 4 + 3 - 2 - 1 = 2016
9 x 8 x 7 x 6 / (5 + 4) x (3 + 2 + 1) = 2016

There are probably at least fifty more variations that I didn't bother to work out.

Comment: Similarly, anything with 9 x 8 x 7 x 4 plus any combination that equals zero will work as well.

Answer (score 15):

I have found all 3,020 expressions satisfying the given restrictions along with four others:

- The digits 1-9 must be in order.
- You are not allowed to take the square root of $1$ or $0$.  Without this restriction we could have arbitrarily complex expressions.
- Every subexpression must have a rational value.  This excludes expressions that involve terms like $\log[2]\sqrt{2}=\frac{1}{2}$.  Without this restriction we could have arbitrarily complex expressions.
- Decimal points are not allowed, since it is not clear how we are allowed to use them.

My algorithm works as follows.  I compute a table of values $\mathtt{terms}$, where each element $\mathtt{terms}[i,j]$ represents the possible values of a subexpression starting at the $i$-th number and spanning $j$ numbers.  As an example, take the expression:

$$((1 - (2 \times (3 - 4) + 5)) + 6) \times 7 \times 8 \times 9$$

The term $3-4$ is associated with $\mathtt{terms}[3,2]$, and the term $7 \times 8 \times 9$ is associated with $\mathtt{terms}[7,3]$.  The entire expression is associated with $\mathtt{terms}[1,9]$, and the individual numbers are associated with $\mathtt{terms}[*,1]$

Each $\mathtt{terms}[i,j]$ is a list of key-value pairs: the keys are the values of that subexpression, and the values are the ways of reaching that value.  For example:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathtt{terms}[1, 2] = \{\quad
3 &\to \{1+2\ (1)\},\\
-1 &\to \{1-2\ (1)\}, \\
 2 &\to \{1 \times 2\ (1)\}, \\
\tfrac{1}{2} &\to \{1 \div 2\ (1)\}
\quad\}
\end{align}
$$

A quick note: for binary operators (all of them except the square root) I store the operator, the left and right-hand operands, *and* the size of the left operand.  The last one is necessary in the second part of the algorithm, and above and below it is shown in parenthesis.  Another example:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathtt{terms}[1, 3] = \{\quad
6 &\to \{1+5\ (1),\ 1\times 6\ (1),\ 3+3\ (2),\ 2\times 3\ (2)\},\\
0 &\to \{1+(-1)\ (1),\ 3-3\ (2),\ \sqrt{0}\},\\
1 &\to \{3\div 3\ (2),\ \log[3](3)\ (2),\ \sqrt{1}\}, \\
\vdots
\end{align}
$$

A few notes:

- For all operators, only the values of the operands are stored instead of the entire subexpressions.  This is what makes this method efficient.
- Square roots do not need a length stored with them, since they apply to a single subexpression.
- The restriction on square roots of $0$ and $1$ is not applied at this stage (they add at most a constant overhead).

The algorithm that computes $\mathtt{terms}$ is as follows:

- Loop over $\ell=1\ldots 9$:

  - Loop over $i=1\ldots 10 - \ell$:

    - If $\ell = 1$, initialize $\mathtt{vals}=\{i \to \{i\}\}$.
    - Otherwise, initialize $\mathtt{vals}=\{\}$ and loop through $k=1\ldots \ell-1$:

      - Get the possible values of the left-hand and right-hand operands.  These are: $$\begin{align}\mathtt{LHS}&=\mathtt{terms}[i,k] \\ \mathtt{RHS}&=\mathtt{terms}[i+k,\ell-k]\end{align}$$
      - Construct all possible terms: $$a\circ b\ (k);\ a\in\mathtt{LHS},\ b\in\mathtt{RHS},\ \circ\in\{+,-,\times,\div,\log\}$$
      - Add to $\mathtt{vals}$ all terms that result in a rational value.
    - Repeatedly take a the square root of each term in $\mathtt{vals}$.  If the result is a rational value, add it to $\mathtt{vals}$.
    - Set $\mathtt{term}[i,\ell]=\mathtt{vals}$.

Next we traverse $\mathtt{terms}$ in reverse order.  Starting with $\mathtt{terms}[1,9]$ we get all the ways to make $2016$, then recursively get all the ways to make each subexpression, ignoring $\sqrt{1}$ and $\sqrt{0}$.  This results in a list of 32,282 expressions.  I then normalize the expressions using the following transformations:

$$
\begin{align}
\cdots+(x_1+\cdots+x_n)+\cdots &\to \cdots+x_1+\cdots+x_n+\cdots \\
\cdots\times(x_1\times\cdots\times x_n)\times\cdots &\to \cdots\times x_1\times\cdots\times x_n\times\cdots \\
\cdots+(x-y)+\cdots &\to ((\cdots+x)-y)+\cdots \\
\cdots\times(x\div y)\times\cdots &\to ((\cdots\times x)\div y)\times\cdots
\end{align}
$$

This prevent us from counting expressions like $(1+2)+3$ and $1+(2+3)$ as different.  After this step, there are only 3,020 distinct expressions.  The full list is available [here](https://gist.github.com/robertcampion/85decaebb49993757ab1). Note that this list uses *Mathematica* notation: $\times\to\mathtt{*},$ $\div\to\mathtt{/},$ $\sqrt{x}\to\mathtt{Sqrt[}x\mathtt{]},$ and $\log[b](x)\to\mathtt{Log[}b\mathtt{,}x\mathtt{]}$.

Of particular note are the expressions:

```
(1+Log[2,Log[3,4+5]])*6*7*8*Sqrt[9]
(1+Log[2,Log[3,4+5]+6])*7*8*9
```

(i.e:)

$$
(1+\log[2](\log[3](4+5)))\times 6\times 7\times 8\times\sqrt{9} \\
(1+\log[2](\log[3](4+5)+6))\times 7\times 8\times 9
$$

Each of which use $\log$ twice, with two different bases!

Answer (score 12):

A variation on Jon Mark Perry's answer:

> (1 + 2 - 3 - 4) x (5 - 6) x 7 x 8 x 9

I wonder how many such 'monotonic' solutions there are?

Comment: LegionMammal got you covered ;)

Answer (score 12):

Using all operations and functions

> $9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot \sqrt{4} \cdot \log_2(1+\frac{6}{5-3})$

Answer (score 11):

How about:

> $(9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7)(6 - 2)\frac{5 - 3}{\sqrt4}\times1$

Answer (score 11):

I had code lying around that solves this exact problem, and the first thing it spat out was:

> (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7) * 8 * 9

Comment: This is very nice, but aside from the personal background, it is a subset of [Pietro Majer’s answer from a day earlier](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28440); it seems a bit odd to accept this in preference to that.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I agree - I didn't notice the equivalence to one of the answers in [Pietro's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28440) when I wrote it. I probably should have done. After posting, I did find it in the brute forced list linked to in [LegionMammal978's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28465/19949), but it's buried way down the list in the middle. I think it's the nicest and simplest answer of any of them.

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine: I see, and I follow your advice.

Answer (score 9):

A simple answer:

> 1·2·3·6·7·8 + 0·4·5·9 = 2016; based off of the fact that 2016=2<sup>5</sup>·3<sup>2</sup>·7.

If that feels too cheaty, then try this:

> 1·2·3·6·7·8 + 4 + 5 - 9 = 2016

Comment: you can't use 0...

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Where does it say that?

Comment: implicitly in the Q

Comment: @JonMarkPerry See my second version if you want to be satisfied.

Comment: Note that log(1)=0, so you could easily convert your first expression into something that works, e.g. `log[4](1)*5*9`

Answer (score 8):

My favorite so far:

> 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * (5 - 4) / 3 * 2 * 1

Had factorials been allowed, I'd have preferred

> 9 * 8 * 7 * 6! / 5! * 4 / 3 / 2 * 1

Comment: Why would you have preferred the second? The first is so much more elegant.

Answer (score 6):

In the spirit of the question, I felt it was time for a solution that includes all allowed operations, including a decimal point, a logarithm and a square root (using [the hint from Joe Z](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28458/3941) about the general structure of a solution):

> 9. * 8 * 7 * (-6 + 5 + log[2](4) * 3 / √1)

or, with a small tweak from the comment by [@f''](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12408/f), this:

> 9 * 7 * 4 * (2 - 3 / log[5](√((1 + .6) / 8)))

which not only has +, -, *, /, decimal, sqrt, and log, but makes every operation "do something"

Answer (score 5):

> ((8 + 6 + 3 + (2 * 7)) * (9 + 4) * 5) + 1 = 2016

Answer (score 5):

Here's mine:

2016 = (9 * 8 * 7 * 4) + 5 * (1 + 2 + 3 - 6)

The first expression is just the factorization of 2016, the rest is just to spend the other digits in a zero-sum.

Answer (score 4):

This is my answer:

> 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 6 * 7 * 8 / (9-5)

Answer (score 4):

Hehe. Whenever logarithms are allowed:

$$
\log_\frac12\left[\log_{8+7+6-5-4-3}\sqrt{\sqrt{\cdots{\sqrt{\sqrt{9\,}\,}\,}}\,}
\right]
$$

with a total of 2016 square roots.

Answer (score 3):

The truly amazing way to get 2016 is

> ${10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6} \over {5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1}$

Unfortunately, that doesn't answer the question.  But it's close enough, you can fix it:

> ${9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6} \over {.5 + .4 + .3 + .2 + .1}$

But that one is less truly amazing imho.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put the given numbers as follows. $ (\frac{6+3+1}{2\times5}) \times4\times8\times7\times9=2016$