# A truly amazing way of making every possible positive integer

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

This is a follow-up to "[A truly amazing way of making the number 2016](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28439/a-truly-amazing-way-of-making-the-number-2016)":

> For every positive integer $n$, find a mathematical expression that 
>   yields the value $n$ while obeying the following rules:
>
> - Each of the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ is used **exactly once**
> - Decimal points are allowed
> - You may use brackets "(" and ")" to structure your expression, and 
>     to make it well-defined
> - The only allowed mathematical operations are addition (+), 
>     subtraction (-), multiplication (*), division (/); the minus sign may also be used as the sign of a negative number.
> - The only allowed mathematical functions are square-roots and logarithms.
>     Logarithms must be written in the form $\log[b](x)$ to denote the base-$b$ logarithm of number $x$

Note that in particular the following is **not allowed**:

- Juxtaposition of digits (as juxtaposing 1 and 3 to get "31")
- using the digit 0, or using non-decimal digits
- other mathematical operations and functions (cube-roots, exponentiation, factorials, absolute values, trigonometric functions, etc)
- integration, differentiation, limits, matrices, and determinants
- rounding up, rounding down, rounding to the nearest integer

Comment: This problem works just as well when restricted to the natural logarithm and is cleaner IMHO because you won't need the big hint about the base.  Log[x](y). Is eqivalamt to ln(y)/ln(x)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We can use:

> $$\log[2]\left(\frac{1}{\log[3]\left(\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{ \ldots \sqrt{5-\sqrt{4}}}}}_\text{square root repeated $n$ times}\right)}\right) + 6 - 7 - 8 + 9$$

This works because:

> $a^{\overbrace{b \cdot b \ldots b}^\text{$n$ times}} = a^{b^n}$, and since $\sqrt{a} = a^{\frac12}$ we have that $\sqrt{\sqrt{ \ldots \sqrt{5 - \sqrt{4}}}} = 3^{\left(\frac12\right)^n} = 3^{\frac1{2^n}}$
>  Now, $\text{log}[a](a^c) = c$, so $\text{log}[3]\left(3^{\frac1{2^n}}\right) = \frac1{2^n}$
>  Finally, by the same token:
> \begin{equation}\text{log}[2]\left(\frac1{\frac1{2^n}}\right) = \text{log}[2]\left(2^n\right) = n\end{equation}
>  The rest is simply adding the unneeded numbers in a zero sum.

If you want a version with the numbers **in order** for 1 to 9, we can do a small manipulation:

> $$-1\cdot\log[2]\left(\log[3]\left(\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{ \ldots \sqrt{-\sqrt{4}+5}}}}_\text{square root repeated $n$ times}\right)\right) + 6 - 7 - 8 + 9$$

Comment: `you should use code or math formatting for the math, it's much easier to read`

Comment: I hope i haven't changed the meaning of the answer while editing.

Comment: @manshu that's great - thanks :) ) I tried and failed with matjax :(

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is something to bookmark in your browser :)

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Oh, really super edit! Just had to add $2$ blanks at the end of a couple lines.  Thanks - like the overbrace! :) )

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer:$$1/\log[\sqrt4](\underbrace{\surd\surd\cdots\surd}_\text{$n$ times}2)+3-5-6+7-8+9=2^n$$Adjust the added values to get nearby integers. Also, changing the base of the logarithm and the radicand can produce powers of other numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> $\dfrac{(9-8)\times(7-6)-(5-4)}{3-2-1}$

Comment: Mathematically speaking, this has no value.

Comment: i am using the argument that $0=0n$, so $\frac00=n$, but i agree in principle

Comment: No, 0/0 is undefined.

Comment: @Deusovi No, it's not. n/0 is undefined for n!=0, but 0/0 is indeterminate. Undefined means it never gives a number. Indeterminate means that it can give different numbers in different contexts. For instance, the limit of n/n as n approaches zero is 1, and also 0/0. The limit of 2n/n as n approaches zero is 2, and also 0/0.

Comment: @hvd: Nope, 0/0 is undefined. It's an indeterminate form, which means if $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = \lim_{x \to c} g(x) = 0$, then $\lim{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ can be any number. However, if you're not doing a limiting process, then 0/0 is undefined.

Comment: @Deusovi "It's an indeterminate form" means something different from undefined. http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57322.html Are you using "undefined" in its ordinary English meaning? If so, you're not wrong, but the argument is somewhat pointless. I'm willing to concede that there are dictionaries out there that provide definitions of "undefined" that agree with you. But in mathematics, undefined and indeterminate are different.

Comment: @hvd: The limit of the quotient of two functions going to zero is indeterminate. The actual calculation "zero divided by zero" is undefined. Indeterminate forms are only a property of limits.

Comment: @Deusovi If you're going to ignore a request for clarification and an external reference to just repeat your previous assertion, there's no point in continuing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36618/discussion-between-deusovi-and-hvd).

Answer (score 1):

With $n$ squareroots:

$$\log_\frac7{8+6}\left[\log_{5+\frac{4\times2}{3-1}}\sqrt{\sqrt{\dots\sqrt{9\,}\,}\,}\right]$$

Because for *any* number $x$

$$\log_\frac12\left[\log_x\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{\dots\sqrt{x\,}\,}\,}}_\text{n square roots}\right]\equiv n$$