# A breathtaking way of making every possible positive integer

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

This is a follow-up question to my older puzzle "[A truly amazing way of making the number 2016](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28439/a-truly-amazing-way-of-making-the-number-2016)" and to my other older puzzle "[A truly amazing way of making every possible positive integer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28444/a-truly-amazing-way-of-making-every-possible-positive-integer)". My favorite solution to the first puzzle observed that

> $~~~~2016 ~=~ (1+2+3+4+5+6+7)*8*9$.

Note that in this solution the digits occur in a neat increasing order!
The solution to the second puzzle gives for every positive integer $n$ a mathematical expression that yields the value $n$ while obeying the following five rules:

> 1. Each of the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ is used **exactly once** (while digit $0$ is not used).
> 2. Decimal points are allowed.
> 3. One may use brackets "(" and ")" to structure your expression, and 
>      to make it well-defined.
> 4. The only allowed mathematical operations are addition (+), 
>      subtraction (-), multiplication (*), division (/); the minus sign may also be used as the sign of a negative number.
> 5. The only allowed mathematical functions are square-roots and logarithms.
>      Logarithms must be written in the form $\log[b](x)$ to denote the base-$b$ logarithm of number $x$.

(Note that juxtaposition of digits, non-decimal digits, cube-roots, exponentiation, factorials, absolute values, trigonometric functions, rounding, limits, etc are strictly forbidden in this puzzle.)

---

Now in this breathtaking follow-up puzzle, I ask you to find a solution that combines the good properties of the solutions for the two older puzzles:

> **New puzzle:** For every positive integer $n$, find a mathematical expression
>
> - that yields the value $n$,
> - that obeys the five rules 1.-5.as listed above,
> - and that contains the digits in increasing order (when read from left to right).

(The solution does not require any tricks. No lateral thinking. 
The expression/string can be written in a single line, with the nine digits occurring in increasing order.)

Comment: So wrt your $\log[b](x)$ rule - $b$ and $x$ would have to be consecutive digits, or are you letting the base slide here?

Comment: So, as in the previous one the use of n is allowed to be in the formula I'm assuming? if so there are a lot of answers that could further simplify what was done in the previous puzzle and meet the requirements of this one.

Comment: I have limited mathematical background - what methods would people use to answer such a question. Would an evolutionary algorithm be used, or would a solution be discovered manually by starting with a solution and building backwards?

Comment: would Paul's answer http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28444/a-truly-amazing-way-of-making-every-possible-positive-integer; work if we write $-\sqrt4+5$?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simple

> $ \kern4em\llap{ 1 } = \log\, [ 1/2 \!~ ]  \Bigl( \log\, [ \!\: 3{-}4{+}5{+}6{+}7{-}8 \!~ ]  \bigl(       \sqrt 9  ~ \bigr)  \Bigr) \raise{-2ex}\strut $
>  
>  $ \kern4em\llap{ 2 } = \log\, [ 1/2 \!~ ] \biggl( \log\, [ \!\: 3{-}4{+}5{+}6{+}7{-}8 \!~ ]  \Bigl( \sqrt{\surd 9} ~ \Bigr) \biggr) $
>  
>  $\kern4.5em \vdots$
>  
>  $ \kern4em\llap{ n } = \log\, [ 1/2 \!~ ] \Biggl( \log\, [ \!\: 3{-}4{+}5{+}6{+}7{-}8 \!~ ] \biggl( ~ \underbrace { \!\!\sqrt{\sqrt{\cdots\surd 9 }\,} \!\!\!\!\!\! }_n ~\quad \biggr) \Biggr) $
>  
>  $ \kern4em     {   } = \log_{\frac12} \log_{\!\; 9} \!\: 9 \!\: \raise{1.3ex}( \!\!\: \strut^\frac12 \! \raise{1.3ex})^n \raise{-3ex}\strut $
>  
>  $ \kern4em     {   } = \log_{\frac12} \bigl( \frac12 \bigr)^n $

Complex

> $ \kern4em\llap{ n } = \log\, [ 1/2 \!~ ] \Bigl( \log\, [ \!\: 3{+}4{+}5{-}6{-}7 \!\: ] \biggl( \sqrt{\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{ 8{-}9 \raise{1.8ex}{\,} } \strut \,}\,} ~ \biggr) \Bigr) $

Side note

> $ \kern4em\llap{ \raise{.2ex}\biggl( n } = \log_{ \, \ln \!\!\: \surd e } \ln \sqrt{\sqrt{ \cdots \surd e \, }\,} \; \raise{.2ex}\biggr) $

Original

> $$ 1 = \log[1/2] \Bigl( \log[3] \Bigl( \!\, \log[4] \, \bigl( (-5)-6+7+8 \bigr) ~\cdot~                   \root\of{\surd 9 \,}        \, \Bigr)  \Bigr) $$
>  $$ 2 = \log[1/2] \left( \log[3] \left(      \log[4] \, \bigl( (-5)-6+7+8 \bigr) ~\cdot~          \root\of{\root\of{\surd 9 \,}\,}    ~\, \right) \right) $$
>  $$ 3 = \log[1/2] \left( \log[3] \left(      \log[4] \, \bigl( (-5)-6+7+8 \bigr) ~\cdot~ \root\of{\root\of{\root\of{\surd 9 \,}\,}\,} ~\, \right) \right) $$
>  $$\vdots \qquad\qquad$$
>  $$\begin{array}{rl} n \kern-1em & = \: \log_{\frac12} \log_3 \raise{.5ex}\Bigl( \bigl( \log_4 4 \bigr) \root\of {9 \,} ^{ \bigl( \frac12 \bigr)^n } \; \raise{.5ex}\Bigr) \\[1ex]             & = \: \log_{\frac12} \log_3 \raise{.5ex}\Bigl( 3^{ \bigl( \frac12 \bigr)^n } \; \raise{.5ex}\Bigr) \\[1ex]             & = \: \log_{\frac12} \left( \frac12 \right)^n \end{array}$$

Answer (score 12):

How about:

> $n = \log [1 - 2 + 3]\left(\left(-4 + 5\right)\text{/}\left({\log\left[\sqrt{-6 + 7 + 8}\right]\left(\sqrt {\sqrt {\ldots\sqrt { \sqrt9}}}\right)}\right)\right)$
>  $\;\;\;= \log[2]\left(1/\left(\log[3]\left(\underbrace{\sqrt {\sqrt {\ldots\sqrt3}}}_{\text{$\sqrt{\phantom0}$repeated $n$ times}}\right)\right)\right)$
>  $\;\;\;= \log_2\left(1/\left(\log_3\left(3^\frac1{2^n}\right)\right)\right)$
>  $\;\;\;= \log_2\left(1/\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)\right)$
>  $\;\;\;= \log_2\left(2^n\right)$
>  $\;\;\;= n$
>  Also, by using *no* repetitions of $\sqrt{\phantom0}$ (as per the second line) we get $n = 0$
>  Likewise, by substituting the $/$ with $\cdot$ we get, as a bonus, $-n$ for all $n$ repetitions of $\sqrt{\phantom0}$

Answer (score 6):

Here is the answer I had in mind:

> $ \kern4em\llap{ 1 } = \log\, [ (1+2+3+4)/5 \!~ ]  \Bigl( \log\, [ \!\: \sqrt{-6+7+8} \!~ ] (9)  \Bigr) \raise{-2ex}\strut $ 
>  $ \kern4em\llap{ 2 } = \log\, [ (1+2+3+4)/5 \!~ ]  \Bigl( \log\, [ \!\: \sqrt{\surd-6+7+8} \!~ ] (9)  \Bigr) \raise{-2ex}\strut $ 
>  $\kern4.5em \vdots$ 
>  $\kern4.5em \vdots$ 
>  $ \kern4em\llap{ n } = \log\, [ (1+2+3+4)/5 \!~ ]  \Bigl( \log\, [ \!\: \underbrace { \!\!\sqrt{\sqrt{\cdots\surd-6+7+8}}}_n \!~ ] (9)  \Bigr) \raise{-2ex}\strut $